# Geodesic crosses every parallel in a surface of revolution.

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

In the book Elementary Differential Geometry, by Andrew Pressley, the author proves that a geodesic will cross every parallel of a surface of revolution. I'm not understanding why.

Let's parametrise the surface of revolution by $\sigma(u,v)=(f(u)\cos v,f(u) \sin(v), g(u))$.

Let the surface be at a distance $> \Omega$ from the axis of rotation.

Let $u_0$ be the least upper bound of u on a geodesic, and let $\Omega+2\epsilon$, with $\epsilon>0$, be the radius of the parallel at $u=u_0$. $\Omega$ is the 'angular moment' on the geodesic, which is shown to be constant everywhere in the geodesic.

We're able to deduce that for $u$ sufficiently close to $u_0$, we have $|\dot u| \geq \sqrt{ 1-\left(\frac{\Omega}{\Omega+\epsilon}\right)^2}>0 $.

How can we can state the geodesic (other than a meridian or a parallel) will cross every parallel with this information?

Comment: This is not true even for the sphere right?

Comment: @ArcticChar I've added a few things, namely an assumption where the surface is always at a certain distance from the axis of rotation.

Comment: Does parallel means the curves where $u$ is constant?

Comment: @ArcticChar yes, I think so.

Comment: Then some parallel might be geodesics (for the extreme case, if your surface is the cylinder, all parallel are geodesics and they do not cross each other).

Comment: @ArcticChar You're right. I think, in this section of the book, the author is trying to use the Clairaut's theorem to determine the qualitative behaviour of geodesics other than meridians and parallels ( with u as a stationary point of f )

Comment: What is the constant  angular moment $\Omega$ of a geodesic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the geodesic fails to cross every parallel, then either (a) it intersects a "maximum/minimum" parallel $u=u_0$ tangentially or (b) it approaches a parallel $u=u_0$ asymptotically. In either event, we must have $\dot u$ either equal to or approaching $0$ on the geodesic. This contradicts the positive lower bound on $|\dot u|$ given in the text.

Comment: thanks Ted ;) ..

Comment: You're most welcome. If you want to look at another source besides Pressley, these sorts of issues show up in Exercises 18 and 23--27 on pp.  77-78 of my (free) differential geometry text, linked in my profile. (Pressley does have answers to all his exercises; I have answers/hints only for exercises marked with an asterisk.)

Answer (score 0):

The course of a geodesic depends on initial radius and angle $(r_i ,\psi_i). $  Assume a minimum radius $r_{min}$ is provided on the surface of revolution of Gaussian curvature $K$.

If $K >0$  then the geodesic runs radially at / above the Clairaut's minimum radius $ ~ r_{Clairaut} = r_i \sin \psi_i > r_{min}, r=f(u), $ $\psi$ is angle geodesic makes to the meridian or $ (\pi/2-\psi) $ to the parallel. It makes tangential contact and reverses after touching $r=r_{Clairaut}~$. There are two minimum radius locations on a convex surface. *Geodesic does not cross all parallels*

If $K=0$  the geodesic extends indefinitely around/along the z-axis.  *Geodesic crosses all parallels*

If $K <0$ then there are three cases.

1. If $ r_{min}=  r_{Clairaut} ~$ then there are infinite spiral rotations for asymptotic reach at $~ r=r_{min}$. *Geodesic crosses all parallels*
2. If $ r_{min}< r_{Clairaut}~ $ then the course and behaviour are just like when $K<0$. *Geodesic does not cross all parallels*
3. If $ r_{min}>  r_{Clairaut}~ $ the geodesic goes to infinity. *Geodesic  crosses all parallels*